# Relation between factorial and number of combinations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, factorial

Suppose you have a list of distinct natural or integer numbers

$$\mathcal{L}=\{1,3,2,5,\dots\},$$

with length $N$.

**Is there a formal proof of following relation?** $$ N = \biggl\lceil \sqrt{\frac{N!}{(N-2)!}}\biggr\rceil = \bigl\lceil \sqrt{2\cdot\#}\bigr\rceil $$ Here $\#$ is the number of unique pairwise (different) combinations of the list $\mathcal{L}$ (= length of list $\mathcal{P}$), $\mathcal{P}$ is the list of unique pairwise (different) combinations of list $\mathcal{L}$, $\lceil \bullet \rceil$ is the ceil function (Gauss bracket).

**Example 1**: $$\mathcal{L}=\{2,5,7\},$$

$$\mathcal{P}=\left\{ \begin{matrix}
     \{2  ,   5\}\\
     \{2  ,   7\}\\
     \{5  ,   7\}\\
\end{matrix} \right\},$$

$$ N=3, \quad \# = 3, $$

$$ 3 = \biggl\lceil \sqrt{\frac{3!}{(3-2)!}}\biggr\rceil = \bigl\lceil \sqrt{2\cdot3}\bigr\rceil $$

**Example 2**: $$\mathcal{L}=\{1,2,3,4,5\},$$

$$\mathcal{P}=\left\{ \begin{matrix}
     \{1  ,   2\}\\
     \{1  ,   3\}\\
     \{1  ,   4\}\\
     \{1  ,   5\}\\
     \{2  ,   3\}\\
     \{2  ,   4\}\\
     \{2  ,   5\}\\
     \{3  ,   4\}\\
     \{3  ,   5\}\\
     \{4  ,   5\}\end{matrix} \right\},$$

$$ N=5, \quad \# = 10, $$

$$ 5 = \biggl\lceil \sqrt{\frac{5!}{(5-2)!}}\biggr\rceil = \bigl\lceil \sqrt{2\cdot10}\bigr\rceil $$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not quite understand the notation.  Is $\#={N \choose 2}=\frac{N(N-1)}{2}$?

Comment: Usually, "permutation" means that order matters, so that (1,2) and (2,1) should be counted as different.  Since you are considering them the say, you have "combinations".

Comment: @Teepeemm Thank you, something learned today. I will update the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You already know the right equality from
$$\frac{N!}{(N-2)!}=N(N-1)=2\#$$
It remains to show that $N=\lceil\sqrt{N(N-1)}\rceil$. To do this, simply note that $N(N-1)=N^2-N$ is between $(N-1)^2=N^2-2N+1$ and $N^2$ if $N\ge2$.

Comment: @Desperado yeah, oops...

Comment: I upvoted your answer, now you're over 100k. Congrats

Comment: @SineoftheTime thanks!

Comment: You don't need to develop $(N-1)^2$ to see that $(N-1)^2 < N(N-1) < N^2$. It's just because $N-1 < N$ and all the factors are positive.